# "SHSetKnownFolderPath" API doesn't work as expected on Windows 10

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am using "SHSetKnownFolderPath" win32 API to change users "Desktop"(`c:\users\administrator\Desktop`) folder location programatically to `D:\Desktop`. Folder location changes as expected to `D:\Desktop`. There is a "Location" tab shown on this folder which tells where the folder currently resides. But "Location" tab should be shown only on `D:\Desktop` folder as its current desktop folder but the "Location" tab is shown on both folders (`c:\users\administrator\Desktop`) and (`D:\Desktop`).

Following is code I am using to change folder location

```
if(S_OK == SHSetKnownFolderPath( FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, L"D:\\Desktop"))
    return TRUE;
```

The above problem is only on "Windows 10", on Windows 7 "Location" tab is shown only on (`D:\Desktop`) folder. I tried changing the Desktop location using "Location" tab which is shown when you right click and go to properties. Folder location changed to (`D:\Desktop`) and also the Location tab was shown only on (`D:\Desktop`).

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does the location tab on old folder persist after reboot?

Comment: Yes it persist after reboot.